# <td> fix width and height expandable when too much text

Tags: php, html, css

can somebody help me here?
im doing a bulletin using phpmysql and got a problem on my table.
the  elements should not expand on its width, but when i put too much text, the width automatically expand and destroy the alignment of the table

all i want is to make the  fix on its width and expand its height when i put  too much text.

What code in css should i need to put to make the width fix on its size for  and the height expandable when theres too much text inside of .

can you give me an example code?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try to place in CSS this rule for the td:

```
white-space:wrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

give a class to your tag and use css to fix the width:

```
<style type='text/css'>
 .noexpand {width:300px;}
</style>


<td class='noexpand'> the content</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. how can i make my text auto break line? The problem i got now when i type too much text, the text wasnt break automatically when displaying in the table. it looks like this one: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa i want to do is this one auto break line